# How to resolve dependencies while installing application on linux (CentOS 7.1)

Tags: linux, installation, centos, git, dependencies

When I tried to install deluge on my CentOS 7.1 I was facing dependency problems due to some el6 which are not meant for CentOS 7.1.

So, I found this page:

https://gist.github.com/dasgoll/111f6f3364e2ab97bc08

The instructions:

```
### Centos 7.1
yum -y install wget
wget hxxp://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
yum -y install deluge-web
systemctl start deluge-web
systemctl stop firewalld
browse http://192.168.3.101:8112
### check it 
yum install deluge-console
```

And my question is:

Why install `nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm` from li.nux.ro (if I'm not wrong it's a repository, correct me if I am)?

I had this dependency problem earlier when I tried installing deluge.

But when I used theabove instructions it resolved all the dependencies automatically for me.

So does is the rpm file installed in the first place used for resolving dependencies?

If not then how can one work around with dependencies while installing a piece of software/application?

Answer (score 0):

`nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm` is package for accessing li.nux.ro repository from `yum`.

It would be more useful to provide the previous message that was reported by yum, because from the thinks I found, there is no `deluge-web` in official centos repository.